# Heikin Ashi Candles and how to set a strategy to enter a trade before the candle closes?

Tags: pine-script, alert, delay, pine-script-v5, timing

I have a fairly successful strategy on the daily timeframe that I use with a Heikin Ashi candle indicator and leveraged ETFs. An issue I’m running into is that the close of the Heikin Ashi candle triggers the buy or sell alert on the standard candle, which is automated through a webhook with my brokerage. However, the Heikin Ashi candle will not print for at least an hour after the day’s close (the event that triggers the alert/trade) — meaning the trade happens after-hours. A fair amount of slippage lowers the return compared to the back-testing results of TradingView, that calculates the trade at the exact moment of the close.  Also, please note that I am also paying for real-time trading data, so there is no delay in the strategy receiving the price action.

After a bit of back in forth with the TradingView help desk, they finally declared that there’s a significant lag in the Heikin Ashi candles, with no explanation why the simple calculations would cause a delay on the close. Note that the system can update the candle every tick when the settings are changed to ‘update every tick’ - but this will cause false alerts to trigger throughout the day.

I’m looking for a workaround that will trigger the trade around 15 minutes before the close, or at least very close to the close (when the red/green state of the daily Heikin Ashi candle is fairly secure).  Any suggestions out there? If it triggered a few minutes after the close, that would be okay too.

I’ve messed around with the ‘input.session’ built-in function to get the timing down, but it will only trigger if I move the timeframe down from daily to hourly.

Here is a simplified version of the strategy with the Heikin Ashi candle indicator and strategy. To remove some complexity and distractions, I removed filtering and candle-counting techniques within the strategy that are irrelevant to the lagging problem in this example, but I can provide the whole script if anyone is really willing the help out and wants to use it.

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="My Strategy", 
     overlay=false,
     calc_on_every_tick=true,
     calc_on_order_fills=true,
     process_orders_on_close=true,
     use_bar_magnifier=true,
     initial_capital=10000,
     default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,
     default_qty_value=100)

//trading window setup
tradingWindow = input.session("1500-1605", title="Trading Window")
inTradingWindow = not na(time(timeframe.period, tradingWindow))
bgcolor(color=inTradingWindow ? color.new(color.green, 90) : color.new(color.white, 99))



// Calculation HA Indicator Values
haTicker = ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
haOpen = request.security(haTicker, 'D', open)
haHigh = request.security(haTicker, 'D', high)
haLow = request.security(haTicker, 'D', low)
haClose = request.security(haTicker, 'D', close)

plotcandle (haOpen, haHigh, haLow, haClose, 
     title='HA', color=haOpen < haClose ? color.green : color.red, 
     wickcolor=haOpen < haClose ? color.green : color.red, 
     bordercolor=haOpen < haClose ? color.green : color.red)

// Calculation MA Values
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="MA Length")
src = input(close, title="MA Source")
offset = input.int(title="MA Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = ta.sma(src, len)
plot(out, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=offset)

// Calculation of Conditional Entry and Exits
long = haOpen < haClose
longexit= haOpen > haClose 
if (inTradingWindow and long)
    strategy.entry(id="Entry", direction=strategy.long,comment="BUY")
if (inTradingWindow and longexit)
    strategy.close(id="Entry",comment="SELL")
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `haTicker = ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)` in pinescript.
And if the help desk confirm that there is delay...
I will recalculate heikinashi from a standard candle chart and value.
Then apply my strategy.

Comment: I will give this a shot and see if there's an improvement, but it seems like the calculations would cause the same delay as the built-in function.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Calculating the HA candles from the regular candles are simple mathematical operations. Those should not cause any delay.